# Any provision for taking a second class feature?

Tags: dnd-4e, class-feature

Can a Ranger, at some point in it's career, take both Archery style and Two-handed style class features in order to broaden their efficacy? Can a Rogue take both Artful Dodger and Cunning Sneak or Brutal Scoundrel? If so, when and how is this done?

Comment: This is actually a class specific question. Which, specific, class are you interested in? What level range, and what are you trying to *achieve* with this class feature?

Comment: I'm actually interested in understanding it in a broad sense. Are you saying that some classes allow the accumulation of all (or at least some) of their class features? If that's the case I'll amend my question to ask for a list/array of those which can and when and how they do so. The idea would be to gain the depth of all a class has to offer. Considering the example of the Ranger in the initial query, to be able to have a Ranger that's got _both class features_ and is thus good at range and up close.

Comment: We *really* don't like list questions here. Frame your question in terms of an actual problem you're having. For example, a multiple-range ranger is a completely different beast than a warlock that can qualify for multiple pacts than etc...

Comment: Edited for specificity, but I really am interested in how this mechanic would relate to classes in general. I have a pretty good handle on multi/hybrids, but there are times where I'd just like to be able to have _all_ of the benefits of my class.

Comment: I've answered the question as asked, but I'm left with the sense that there is no real clear end here. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The key to effectiveness is specialization. You should not even want to take multiple class features.

Comment: @wax eagle - I appreciate your answer and it's quite clear. The RAW allow one to take the long way around to sort of accomplish what could be a simple and natural way to broaden a character. Andras - I have little interest in specialization. I much prefer to dabble with wimps running 14s across the board than have a 20STR and a bunch of 8s. Just personal preference. I'm not in it to win it.

Comment: Good luck? But if you're new to 4e you may find that a rather..frustrating experience. (most characters need to hit to do anything, starting stats below 18 mean you don't hit very much)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the answer is no.

In practice, the answer is...sort of, but not really, and definitely not as well. If it's possible it will be via feats and/or paragon paths.

For the specific cases you've mentioned:

- With the ranger, the only class feature of archery style is the Defensive Mobility bonus feat. So in this case, if you play a Two weapon ranger, and take Defensive Mobility you've technically gained the class feature. However, you would *not* qualify as an Archery Style ranger to, say, qualify for the paragon paths that requires it (namely Battlefield Archer). Going the other direction, you can take Toughness as a feat, but you can't really replace the class feature allowing you to wield one handed weapons in your off hand (there *could* be a PP that does it, but I'm not aware of one and a cursory search of the compendium did not reveal one).
- The Rogue is a bit tougher.  As pointed out in the comments, in Epic you can pick up a second Rogue Talent with the feat Versatile Rogue. The three class features (Rogue Talents) you listed are the following, if it's possible to replicate the results in another manner I've included the method:

  - CHA mod to opportunity attacks.

    - Depending on how high your CHA mod is, this could be replaced by Devensive Mobility.
  - easier hiding, lower movement penalty to stealth

    - The Sneak's trick utility power allows this to some degree. But it's a power for the Thief and not available to a Scoundrel rogue. There are a couple of encounter utilities that also provide similar benefits, taking those would provide similar benefits to this class feature.
  - STR mod to SA damage
    -This one simply isn't replicable via any means.

With the methods I've listed above you won't qualify for the riders, but with the epic feat you will.

4e classes are designed for the most part to be pretty compartmentalized and dipping into other class features is *in general* not supported. There are some cases where it's possible (especially in cases where the feature provides a bonus feat or something that can be replicated with a feat), but they are going to be epic level feats and by that time you may not have the flexibility to properly utilize them.

So the long and short is that you can rarely just grab another class feature, but more often you can replicate the functionality.

Comment: If you're looking for a class that *does* allow for the addition of class features natively as you level, the essentials Mage (wizard), acquires additional magic schools as she levels up.